# use of perl @ARGV

Tags: perl, argv

In a perl application I'm passing variables around with @ARGV.
When there were always two variables and always the same two no problems.
Now it's got more complicated so I need to "empty" @ARGV before adding to it. So I thought this would work:

```
    foreach (@ARGV)
            {
                pop @ARGV;
            }
```

It doesn't. When there are four elements it removes only two.
Any idea why that should be?
Or any other way of emptying it?

Comment: Use Getopt::Long!!!

Answer (score 5):

> In a perl application I'm passing variables around with @ARGV.

This is a poor design and should be avoided. If you need to pass values around, use function arguments, or at least your own global variable. Don't (ab)use a special variable for this.

> Now it's got more complicated so I need to "empty" @ARGV before adding to it.

If you want to make an array empty, assign an empty list to it:

```
@ARGV = ();
```

Comment: I'd quite forgotten I could do that. Perfect thanks.

Comment: It's a web application and the program is kind of recursive it calls itself and other programs that call it in turn.
I should have used an external scratchpad - but it was built many years ago when things were simpler - and it's grown

Answer (score 5):

Your mistake: you are using `foreach` (extracting list elements) and modifying (`pop`) the **same array**! To quote [perlsyn](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops):

> If any part of LIST is an array, `foreach` will get very confused if you add or remove elements within the loop body, for example with `splice`. **So don't do that.**

The following illustrates what is happening in your code:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

print "ARGV BEFORE: ", scalar(@ARGV), "\n";

my $count = 0;
foreach my $loop (@ARGV) {
    ++$count;
    print "ARGV beginning loop ${count} for ${loop}: ", scalar(@ARGV), "\n";
    pop @ARGV;
    print "ARGV end loop ${count} for ${loop}: ", scalar(@ARGV), "\n";
}

print "ARGV AFTER: ", scalar(@ARGV), "\n";

exit 0;
```

Test run:

```
$ perl dummy.pl 1 2 3 4
ARGV BEFORE: 4
ARGV beginning loop 1 for 1: 4
ARGV end loop 1 for 1: 3
ARGV beginning loop 2 for 2: 3
ARGV end loop 2 for 2: 2
ARGV AFTER: 2
```

Compare this to the correct approach that re-checks the list at each iteration:

```perl
while (@ARGV) {
    ++$count;
    print "ARGV beginning loop ${count}: ", scalar(@ARGV), "\n";
    pop @ARGV;
    print "ARGV end loop ${count}: ", scalar(@ARGV), "\n";
}
```

```
$ perl dummy.pl 1 2 3 4
ARGV BEFORE: 4
ARGV beginning loop 1: 4
ARGV end loop 1: 3
ARGV beginning loop 2: 3
ARGV end loop 2: 2
ARGV beginning loop 3: 2
ARGV end loop 3: 1
ARGV beginning loop 4: 1
ARGV end loop 4: 0
ARGV AFTER: 0
```

---

That said: **PLEASE** do yourself a favor and re-think your SW architecture/design. Misusing Perl variables with defined semantics for own purposes is an *extremely* bad idea.

Comment: As I said earlier I forget a lot as I don't code as often any more.
Thanks for pointing out the weakness using foreach.
I have no reason to spend hundreds of hours re-working an architecture because someone things using a handy shortcut is a bad idea. i think it's a great idea. the only other solution would be a scratchpad and that would add i/o
Why are you all so negative. Perl is not a sacred object - it's just a tool

Comment: The answers are for everyone who reads this in future, not just the person who asked the question.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Perl - I would give the same answer for a misuse of features in *any* SW development environment. "I do/use X, because I can/it works for me" is bad SW development practice and your question exemplifies what problems it can cause.

Answer (score 1):

Did you read [the documentation for `pop()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pop.html)? It says:

> Pops and returns the last value of the array, shortening the array by one element.

So I'm not clear why you think it would empty the array. Perl has a great set of documentation, but it's useless if you don't read it :-)

You can clear an array by assigning an empty list to it, like this:

```
@ARGV = ();
```

But I have to say that using `@ARGV` for this sounds like a terrible idea. `@ARGV` has a defined purpose - it contains the command-line arguments that are passed to your program. There's really no need to use it for anything else. If you want your own array, then just create a new array.

Comment: The help is greatly appreciated. The criticism less so. Whatever is available can be used however you want. 
You think it a terrible idea. I think it's a great idea. Doesn't hurt anybody

Comment: @user1210923 - You say it "doesn't hurt anybody", but the very existence of this question shows that it _did_ hurt somebody: You. By making a poor design decision, you inadvertently made it harder for yourself to modify the program when it became more complex in the future, and possibly also harder for yourself (or anyone else who may one day work with the code) to understand what it's doing. Your design isn't being criticized because it violates some holy dogma, it's being criticized because it makes it harder to maintain and extend your program.

Comment: Ha ha ha! The problem I had, if you recall, was not due to the use I make of @ARGV but that I had forgotten how to remove the values of an array.
Using that system variable makes life very simple and it's easy to follow - considering iterative calls are rarely easy to follow.
Your value judgement that this is a poor design decision is unwelcome and not  especially interesting. 
As I said I'm always grateful for advice on a particular problem. Anything else please keep to yourself.
Although you claim not to be invoking dogma it really does come across that way.

Comment: @user1210923: Well, we haven't seen enough of your code to see exactly how you're using `@ARGV`. But I bet that if we did, we could show you a much better way to achieve what you're trying to do without abusing Perl's built-in variables.

Comment: @user1210923: *Anything else please keep to yourself.* I'm afraid it doesn't work like that. The price of asking the experts on this site for advice is that they will sometimes give you more advice than you think you want - but it will always be advice that they think you need :-)

Comment: You'd lose your bet Dave.  Had there been another way apart from an external scratchpad which would use real i/o I would have found it.
I don't believe built-in variables can be abused. What a ridiculous concept.
I happily accept it was thought I needed that advice bur it was really not relevant and stank of a holier-than-thou attitude.
I've been involved in IT for nearly 50 years and have coded far more languages than I care to remember and on far more architectures too. OK so as an OAP I get a bit forgetful and that was my problem. Abusing variables? How quaint

Comment: @user1210923: There's absolutely no point in continuing this conversation unless you're prepared to share more of your code so that we can see just why re-using `@ARGV` is such a good idea.